# Magento 2 custom Model in Component not Working

Tags: magento2.2.2, modal-popup, component

Ive created a custom component with a template in Magento_Checkout summary :

this is my modal-custom.html:

```
<div id="modal-content">TEST</div>
<button id="example-modal-button" data-bind="event:{ click: openModal}">
Open modal
</button>
```

And Here is my js:

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'ko'
    ],
    function (Component, $, modal, ko) {
        'use strict';
        var options = {
            autoOpen: true,
            responsive: true,
            clickableOverlay: false,
            modalClass: 'modal-custom',
            title: 'Popup',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Click Me',
                click: function () {
                    console.log('test')
                }
               }]
            };
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/view/summary/modal-custom'
            },
            initialize: function (elem) {
                this._super();
                this.startModal();
                return this;
            },
            startModal: function () {
                var ele = $('#modal-content');
                var popup = modal(options, ele); //This is causing the error possibly the ele var;
            },
            openModal: function () {
                $('#modal-content').modal('openModal');
            }

        });
    }
);
```

It's all fine apart from that when I initialize:

> this.startModal();

it Gives Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`

Any helps why it can't find/fire/initialize the modal $('#modal-content')?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
        startModal: function () {
            var ele = $('#modal-content');
            var popup = ele.modal(options);
        }
```

Alternatively you could also get rid of the `startModal` method and go with:

```
        openModal: function () {
            $('#modal-content').modal(options).modal('openModal');
        }
```

Though your startModal is neater.

Comment: I've tried it doesn't give errors but I don't think it initialises : the error now is on click **openModel**  `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on modal prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'openModal'` However the 2 option alternative worked !

Comment: @JulianoVargas Might it be that your modal-content doesn't exist yet when the `initialize` call is done?

Comment: If this solved your problem, can you accept my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just initialize the Modal widget without any additional logic, you can use `mageInit` bind instead of creating separate model.

For example:

`data-bind="{mageInit: {'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal' : { ..your parameters..}}`"

Hope it helps.